# Android Studio - Gradle project sync failed ,ASCII error occurred

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, ascii

The problem is that when I sync a project on Android Studio. I followed all the steps on the Fire base guide, the "ASCII" error occurred.I already paste my google-services.json file is  in the app folder.

> build.gradle(Project: )

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anikr.communityapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please don't post text files as Images, read about [how to format text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) here and dedicate a few minutes to make your question look readable. We can't help you if you don't put your effort. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Add following line to gradle.properties

```
android.overridePathCheck=true
```

Answer (score 2):

use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` 
and remove firebase-analytics dependency.
This resolved my errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Add following line to gradle.properties(project properies)**

```
android.overridePathCheck=true
```